# NS2-Invalid Command Name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcl, simulator, ns2

I'm using Network Simulator 2 (NS2) to implement/evaluate a MAC protocol. I'm running version 2.35 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've followed the instructions here to setup NS2: http://ramakrishnamundugar.blogspot.com/2012/09/ns-234-installation-in-ubuntu-1204.html

It seems to work as I can type "ns" at the end and get the % symbol. The issue I seem to be getting is that it doesn't seem to recognize the name of my protocol from the TCL file. It gives me the error:

```
    invalid command name "Mac/pa3"
         while executing
    "$val(mac) set repeatTx_ $val(repeatTimes)"
      (file "pa3.tcl" line 45)
```

Where line 45 is as follows:

```
    $val(mac) set repeatTx_ $val(repeatTimes);
```

It seems like it doesn't recognize the name of my protocol. I've implemented the protocol in pa3.cc and pa3.h files respectively. When I type ./configure then "make clean", then "make" from the ns-2.34 directory, it compiles without errors and generates the pa3.o object file.

I thought my TCL file was broken at first but it turns out that if I change the name to 802_11, it works fine with my TCL file. I believe that the error mentioned on line 45 is flagged because it doesn't think I have a protocol called pa3 installed.

Please advise as I've been coming up with dead ends for the past few days. Has anyone used NS2 and can tell me the procedure to add your own protocol? I don't want help evaluating the protocol but it seems I need to make the TCL file somehow recognize my pa3 protocol. I've searched and searched but nothing I've tried has worked.

Thank You.

Comment: I think you have to compile it after your protocol has been compiled to link toward your code, but that's just an idea from top of my head and maybe there's some other changes to do to compile properly.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I run the TCL script with "ns tcl_file.tcl" after I do a: "./configure" "make clean" and then "make". I see the .o object file for the protocol in the directory and everything.. So just to make it clear, I have the .c, .h, .o and .tcl file all within that "ns-2.34/mac" directory.

Comment: I resolved this issue. I was using ns-2.34, and it was giving the errors mentioned. However when I installed 2.35, and did the same exact thing that I did in version 2.34, it worked. So I guess there might be an issue with version 2.34 in Ubuntu.